# how to know if my openssl supports sslv3

Tags: c, linux, shell, openssl

I have openssl installed on my machine. And I'm using openssl as client. I want to know if the openssl supports SSLv3.

Is there an openssl command to know if the SSLv3 is supported in my openssl?

Answer (score 0):

> How to know if my openssl supports sslv3

If SSLv2 or SSLv3 is *not* enabled, then you can check for the preprocessor macros `OPENSSL_NO_SSL2` and `OPENSSL_NO_SSL2` in `opensslconf.h`.

```
#include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
...

#if !defined(OPENSSL_NO_SSL3)
  /* SSLv3 is available */
#endif
```

The defines are created/set by the build system. If you configure with:

```
./config no-ssl2 no-ssl2 no-comp
```

The the build system will define `OPENSSL_NO_SSL2`, `OPENSSL_NO_SSL3` and `OPENSSL_NO_COMP`.